# Limit movement of third person controller to two axes

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's simple: I don't want my 3rd person dude to fall off my world, so I'd like to keep him moving side to side and up and down, like a side scroller. I can't seem to find anyone who's had this issue, for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
```

That won't allow your GameObject to move on the Z-axis.

You can also go a step further and [freeze anything you want](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html).